# LOAD_GLOBAL(dispatcher) appearing when I "Step Into" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am on a Windows 10 computer running a simple tensorflow 2.1 script in VSCode. For some reason when I step into a function the IDE takes me to an odd file with the following written in it:

```
LOAD_GLOBAL(dispatcher), LOAD_FAST(args), LOAD_FAST(kwargs), CALL_FUNCTION_EX{1}, STORE_FAST(relevant_args)
return implement_array_function(
implementation, dot, relevant_args, args, kwargs)
```

Here is the line I'm trying to step into (standard tensorflow/keras, so I didn't think it was worth adding more context):

```
history = model.fit(training_data, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=validation_data)
```

If I step through the file bit by bit, it sometimes changes to say this:

```
LOAD_GLOBAL(dispatcher), LOAD_FAST(args), LOAD_FAST(kwargs), CALL_FUNCTION_EX{1}, STORE_FAST(relevant_args)
return implement_array_function(
implementation, iscomplexobj, relevant_args, args, kwargs)
```

Or this:

```
LOAD_GLOBAL(dispatcher), LOAD_FAST(args), LOAD_FAST(kwargs), CALL_FUNCTION_EX{1}, STORE_FAST(relevant_args)
return implement_array_function(
implementation, stack, relevant_args, args, kwargs)
```

This happens with both VSCode and VSCode - Insiders. What is this and how can I avoid it? I don't know where to start with this so I don't know what other information to provide, so please let me know. In case it's relevant, I haven't changed the "justMyCode" flag, so I assume it is still set to True.